# Existence of primitive of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I had proved that the absolute value of a contour integral of a complex function $f$   around a circle of radius $R$ and center $z_0$ when $R$ tends to $+\infty$ equals $0$ and that $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb C \setminus\{ |z - z_0| < r \}$ ($r$ fixed).

According to the Cauchy Theorem and to Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - Contour Integrals, could I say that $f$ has primitive on the domain of analyticity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. You can give a very simple argument using the Laurent series for $f$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!